# Integrate docked footer

Tags: html, css

I am having a hard time with this. This is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/HMsKa/30/

I am trying to integrate a docked footer for when there is little amounts of content. I am using this site for the code example of how to do this:

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/
http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/layout.css

However, no matter what connotation I put this code into my site, it doesn't work. Could someone show me how I should integrate this with my existing code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check out your the html structure, look in the sticker-footer's html for example.

It has to be somewhat as below:

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- your content -->
        <div class="push"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

As the css file says, I'll recreate it here:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

/*

Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait
http://ryanfait.com/

*/
```

A somewhat edit of your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/HMsKa/36/

You need a `.wrapper` with a `min-height: 100%`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunatly it isnt working quite right. When you drag the window up the footer doesnt remain at the bottom of the page, you can see white space under it! :(

Comment: @JamesWillson sorry a typo, in the `,` which should be `;` here's the fixed one http://jsfiddle.net/HMsKa/36/, and I've updated above.